# Macro delimited lists

Tags: floats, parsing

Floats use macro delimited lists like `\@freelist`.  Source2e shows them using macros like `\@next` and `\@cons` without showing the definitions.  The idea of having self parsing lists is intriguing and probably efficient.

So is there a tutorial somewhere on how to use macro delimited lists?  If not should I write one?

Comment: Like so many of the fancier tricks in the original latex sources, these are documented in appendix D of the TeXBook (the subsection "list macros".)

Comment: not sure what you mean by not showing the definitions, source2e has the full sources, `\@cons`  is defined in `ltdefns.dtx`

Comment: and `\@next` is from `ltoutput.dtx`

Comment: I'm having better luck searching for `\@elt`.

Comment: there are 21 instances of `\let\@elt\something` in latex.ltx

Comment: @JohnKormylo `expl3` offers much more

Comment: I didn't mention expl3 (don't confuse me with @egreg:-) but yes it is pretty efficient for what it does. of course it is big but it has been tuned over several decades and it's unlikely that anyone coding something directly would code it more efficiently. that said, it;s not likely _anyone_ would code a regex interpreter in latex if they aren't Bruno:-)

Comment: Is your question about *these* particular mentioned macros, or about "macro delimited lists" in general?  If the latter, do you mean "lists" in the latex sense of `\item`, or are you referring to something more general, such as might be addressed by the `listofitems` package?  In any event, some sample code might help describe your problem better for readers.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - I wound up writing my own tutorial as an answer (once I found the code for \@cons and \@next).  So the question did serve a purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows the effects of using `\@cons` and `\@next` (more or less).

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=\baselineskip

\makeatletter
\def\printelt#1{{\def\@elt##1{\the##1 }#1}}

% see \@cons: merges #1 and #2 into #1
\def\cons#1#2{\begingroup\let\elt\relax\xdef#1{#1\elt #2}\endgroup}

% see \@next: #1=macro name, #2=list, #3=extra code if not empty, #4=code if empty
\def\next#1#2#3#4{\ifx#2\empty #4\else \expandafter\xnext #2\@@#1#2#3\fi}

\def\xnext \elt #1#2\@@#3#4{\def#3{#1}\gdef#4{#2}}% \@@ used as delimiter
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\expandafter\printelt\csname @freelist\endcsname

\def\mylist{\elt 1}%
\cons{\mylist}{2}%
\cons{\mylist}{3}%
\cons{\mylist}{4}%

\def\elt#1{ #1}
\mylist

\next\test\mylist{}{}
\test

\mylist

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]